# Error in reading date time format

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have tried to run a query to copy datetime from a text file to database.

It gives following error.

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "14-09-2013 00:08:57"
>
> HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY finaltest, line 186, column takendate: "14-09-2013 00:08:57"

But when i tried reading "14-09-2013 15:08:57"

It has given no error.

What is the reason that it don't read the time starting with "00".

Edit: Using this code to perform the operation:

```
COPY finaltest(weight,takendate,lineip) from 'H:\\result.txt' with delimiter','
```

Data from file looks like this:

> 29440.86,05-09-2013 00:08:33,005
>
> 29500.87,05-09-2013 01:08:33,005
>
> 29545.88,05-09-2013 02:08:33,005
>
> 29605.89,05-09-2013 03:08:33,005
>
> 29665.87,05-09-2013 04:08:33,005

Comment: Post the code you are using to copy the dates to the database.

Comment: COPY finaltest(weight,takendate,lineip)
from 'H:\\result.txt'
with delimiter','

Comment: And a few sample lines from `result.txt`. Edit your question and add both information to it.

Comment: 29440.86,05-09-2013 00:08:33,005   /
      29500.87,05-09-2013 01:08:33,005   /
      29545.88,05-09-2013 02:08:33,005   /
      29605.89,05-09-2013 03:08:33,005   /
      29665.87,05-09-2013 04:08:33,005

Comment: What is your locale setting?

Comment: as it came with the software i have not changed any settings

Comment: To make the picture complete, we'd need the table definition for `finaltest` (`\d finaltest` in psql, or copy from pgAdmin) and the version numbers of Postgres and pgAdmin.